# How the get the FiberNode in React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

I want to get the Fiber node in Hook,But don't know how to ?

```js
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  // get the FiberNode in this Component
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: Because some business need,But I don't know how to? And I can't find any info about this :(

Comment: Maybe you might want to rethink what you're doing, except if you're building some kind of devtools for react - you shouldn't need that

Comment: Yes,you are right,but i want to know if there are any API or property that I can get it

Comment: You can't, hence why I said you need to rethink why you need that information

Comment: I found the way, document.getElementById("root")._reactRootContainer._internalRoot.current

Comment: @Thomas.lin you should post that as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the way, document.getElementById("root")._reactRootContainer._internalRoot.current

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to take a look at the **`FiberNode`** instance is by using `html selector`.

1. Open `Dev Tools` in your browser
2. Type the `html selector` of your component, in my case `document.querySelector(".card").__reactFiber` and hit `cmd + Space` and `Tab` buttons to autocomplete - becouse each `FiberNode` has uniq id.

In my case whole selector looks like this `document.querySelector(".card").__reactFiber$n9r3t0wnc2`.

**`FiberNode`** is a part of `React Fiber tree` (Linked List data structure) and contains all internal information about your component such as: `prev and next states`, `props`, `list of hooks` an so on.

[image]

You can also check it inside react `useEffect` hook.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const el = document.querySelector(".card");
        // @ts-expect-error just for the sake of example
        const list = Object.keys(el);
        const keyIdx = list.findIndex((k) => k.indexOf("__reactFiber"));
        // @ts-expect-error just for the sake of example
        console.log(el[list[keyIdx]]);
    }, []);
```

[image]